# Got UnboundLocalError: Local Variable referenced before assignment, but it wasn't

Tags: python, list, variables

I am completely stumped. I looked at other answers to this same question, but none seemed to give the slightest answer as to why I myself am getting this error. I have pretty much 2 of the exact same programs running the same code with the exception of some URL's and Product ID's that it reads from files. The programs are a little bit long, so I put them on [Pastebin Here](http://pastebin.com/AkVJAHrD). I don't expect you to read all the code, the error occurs in the main function where I define PID and then try to use it later in the function. Why does one work perfectly fine and the other does not? As far as I can see they are the same in that part, but maybe I missed something! Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

PS: The error I receive is:

```
UnboundLocalError: Local variable 'PID' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Good practice before asking a question (and necessary for StackOverflow questions that revolve around errors in code) is to create a minimal reproducer -- the smallest possible amount of code that produces the same problem; that minimal amount of code should then be included in the question itself. See http://sscce.org/ or http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, a good chunk of the time, the process of building a minimal reproducer will, itself, enable you to figure out the cause of your problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `findall('CRC-START(.*?)CRC-END', PIDFile.read(), re.S)` on line 202 didn't find anything, PID didn't get declared, boom, `UnboundLocalError`.

This happens because python interpreter makes a preliminary pass on the code, marking encountered variables as local, but it does not (and cannot) check if code that declares them will actually be executed.
Minimal reproducible example of that effect would be this:

```
>>> def foo():
    if 0:
        a = 1
    print a


>>> foo()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    foo()
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 4, in foo
    print a
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I didn't fill that area of the txt yet, I thought it would just find nothing and continue through! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

(Rep not high enough to 'comment') Link doesn't work. Could you maybe provide the code excerpt?

This error occurs when you try to use a variable before it is initialized (or defined depending on your code) - when you try to use a variable outside of its *scope*.  Make sure that your variable WILL be initialized by the reference point.  I'm wondering if you put that in an if-statement that doesn't get entered...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems that you reassign a new list to PID every iteration of a for loop. In the end your PID will contain only the last result.

I think what you really want to do is assign an empty list to PID before the for loop. Maybe after `output = open(outputFile, 'w')` and then append results to PID every iteration. Then you will not get UnboundLocalError even if nothing is found in PID.txt.

Comment: This did not seem to fix it... The loop will really only run once to find the area, as there is only 1 place in the file that it will find CRC-START.